# Parse xml data into an array in C#

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

How can I parse XML data into an array using C#?

```
<details> 
 <row> 
  <var name="Year" value="&quot;2008&quot;" /> 
  <var name="person" value="&quot;10202&quot;" /> 
 </row> 
 <row> 
  <var name="Year" value="&quot;2007&quot;" /> 
  <var name="person" value="&quot;11202&quot;" /> 
 </row> 
</details>
```

Comment: I mean, give us Xml example, class description. More info.

Comment: Yes, but you should probably use a `List` or other typesafe collection instead of an `Array`. How to actually do it depends a bit on the structure of the data in the XML.

Comment: <details>
     <row> 
        <var name="budgetYear" value="&quot;2008&quot;" />
        <var name="account" value="&quot;10202&quot;" />
     </row>
     <row> 
        <var name="budgetYear" value="&quot;2007&quot;" />
        <var name="account" value="&quot;11202&quot;" />
     </row>

Comment: Add this xml to your question, please.

Comment: @Lambo - You should _edit_ the _question_ and add the XML to it.

Comment: Parse into an array of *what*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the example, it looks to me like you are hoping to get this:

```
var rows = XDocument.Load("filename.xml")
                    .Root.Elements()
                    .Select(row => row.Elements()
                                      .ToDictionary(v => v.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                    v => v.Attribute("value").Value);
```

This will create an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>`, where each entry in the `IEnumerable` is a "row" and each entry in the inner dictionaries is a "variable".

---

If you are looking to create a more strongly-typed solution, and can guarantee the XML structure is always two variables, one named `budgetYear` and one named `account`, then something like this would work:

```
// Probably needs a better name.
struct YearAndAccount
{
    private readonly int budgetYear;
    private readonly string accountId;

    public int BudgetYear { get { return this.budgetYear; } }
    public string AccountId { get { return this.accountId; } }

    public YearAndAccount(int budgetYear, string accountId)
    {
        this.budgetYear = budgetYear;
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }
}

var rows = XDocument.Load("filename.xml")
                    .Root.Elements()
                    .Select(row => new YearAndAccount(
                        int.Parse(row.Elements().Single(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == "budgetYear")
                                                      .Attribute("value").Value),
                        row.Elements().Single(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == "account")
                                      .Attribute("value").Value));
```

This will create an `IEnumerable<YearAndAccount>`.

---

The parsing code for the strongly-typed solution is so amazingly icky because your XML is very poorly structured; a better structure would be something like

```
<details>
 <yearAndAccount>
   <budgetYear>2008</budgetYear>
   <account>10202</account>
 </yearAndAccount>
 <yearAndAccount>
   <budgetYear>2007</budgetYear>
   <account>11202</account>
 </yearAndAccount>
</details>
```

in which case the code would simply be

```
var rows = XDocument.Load("filename.xml")
                    .Root.Elements()
                    .Select(row => new YearAndAccount(row.Element("budgetYear").Value,
                                                      int.Parse(row.Element("account").Value)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Xml Serialization/Deserialization in .Net can be achieved by:

1. [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) and Xml*Attributes in System.Xml.Serialization namespace
2. [DataContactSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) and DataContract+DataMember attributes
3. [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) and [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) + Linq - processing raw xml-files.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is called [deserialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) - there are many ways to achieve it.

In the .NET framework, one of the newer classes with good control over how this is achieved is the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx). You can see an example of how it works in the example at the bottom of the linked documentation.

Without concrete examples, this is as far as I can help.

Comment: the problem I want to do is to convert a csv file into a xml but it was overwriting the xml file already there so I was going to read in the data from the xml and add it to the generated data to amend the file. This way I can add in a checker for duplicate data and error checks.

Comment: @Lambo - You can deserialize the XML to a class using one of the serializer classes, then add the CSV data to your list and serialize it out to XML, after removing the duplicates.

Comment: I like that idea, will give it a try and get back to you all.