# How to convert Xml to string array

Tags: c#, xml, string, arrays

Currently the application that I am working on returns XML into a string.

```
String xml = getData();
```

But now I need to convert this to a string array, the Xml will something like this:

```
<details> 
 <row> 
  <Year>2014</Year> 
  <Person>Bob</Person> 
 </row> 
 <row> 
  <Year>2013</Year> 
  <Person>Fred</Person> 
 </row> 
</details>
```

Ive seen how to do this if the XML is saved in a file but this wont be an option. 
Any Ideas?

I would like to have something like a dictionary array or list of arrays with the values looking like this:
year, year, year

person, person, person

Comment: What exactly do you want to have in the array? Each line of the XML? An array with names of the persons? Or anything else?

Comment: Share a format of the array you are expecting from the XML

Comment: Edited to what Im trying to get out of it

Comment: Are you sure your xml has a valid structure? You are declaring elements with 2 attributes (name and value) but without a name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var rows = from row in doc.Root.Elements("row") select row;

//array of person
var persons = rows.Select(o => (string) o.Element("Person")).ToArray();
//array of year
var years = rows.Select(o => (string)o.Element("Year")).ToArray();
```

If you meant to get all element inside `<row>` in single array, try this way :

```
//you can remove OrderBy part if it isn't necessary
var result = rows.SelectMany(o => o.Elements())
                 .OrderBy(o => o.Name.LocalName)
                 .Select(o => (string) o).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without knowing the name "row" or the xml structure at compile time?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is a way. But that depends on possible XML structures you can have. Try to post several sample XMLs, so that we can't hardcode element name "row"

Comment: Well assuming it has a similar structure but perhaps different element names?

Comment: okay, if that is the case, simply replace `Elements("row")` with `Elements()`

Answer (score 0):

As per answer given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484460/parse-xml-data-into-an-array-in-c-sharp)

```
var rows = XDocument.Load("filename.xml")
                    .Root.Elements()
                    .Select(row => row.Elements()
                                      .ToDictionary(v => v.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                    v => v.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Comment: Can I use the string datatype with the xml in as the parameter for the load? otherwise this wont help

Comment: yes you can pass string in load method see the defination `public static XDocument Load(TextReader textReader);`

Comment: Can this method be made dynamic, for example if the amount of attributes and their names are not known at runtime

Comment: It can be made but you have to pass attribute name also dynamically i.e. instead of hardcoding it pass it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "details" is the root element of your XmlFile and the name of the file is "XMLFile1.xml", you can use this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

var rows = doc.GetElementsByTagName("row").Cast<XmlElement>();
var persons = rows.SelectMany(x => x.GetElementsByTagName("Person")
    .Cast<XmlElement>()).ToArray().Select(x => x.InnerText).ToArray();
var years = rows.SelectMany(x => x.GetElementsByTagName("Year")
    .Cast<XmlElement>()).ToArray().Select(x => x.InnerText).ToArray();
```

And don't forget to include the Linq-namespace.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without knowing the name "row" or the xml structure at compile time?